# how to permanently remove source code reference in a .net core application

Tags: .net-core, dockerfile, debug-symbols

I have a .net core application that is compiled in release. I assumed that there wouldn't be any source information available.

but then I see the exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: can't download the license data
   at Common.Credentials.RequestCredentials[a](a licenseId) in /src/Weatherman/Common/Credentials.fs:line 71
```

so, the file names and lines are somehow bundled with the app.

the build is done like this (through a dockerfile):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 as build

WORKDIR /src/
COPY ./Weatherman/Common/Common.fsproj                   ./Weatherman/Common/Common.fsproj
COPY ./Weatherman/Exchange/Exchange.fsproj               ./Weatherman/Exchange/Exchange.fsproj
COPY ./Services/Connector/Connector.fsproj ./Services/Connector/Connector.fsproj
RUN dotnet restore Services/Connector/Connector.fsproj

COPY . /src/
RUN dotnet build --nologo -c Release -o /app --no-restore Services/Connector/Connector.fsproj

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish --nologo -c Release -o /app --no-restore Services/Connector/Connector.fsproj

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1 as final

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
```

so I really assumed that there wouldn't be any debug information left. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you see any pdb files in the publish directory `/app`? Does removing them make a difference?

Comment: you are right! I never assumed it would put the pdb files with the publish function! I have now to figure out how to make sure they are not built

Comment: in release, I don't have the symbols enabled: https://imgur.com/a/Z86fs9u

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your project to not produce debug information. You can add this to all your project files, or to a [`Directory.Build.props`  in the root project directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019):

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
      <DebugType>None</DebugType>
      <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

See more details at https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3689

Comment: but that will prevent the symbols from being built in debug, right?